# How to merge all open tab in single drop-down list in NotePad++?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I'm using Notepad++. My project contains many files.

So, I have 15-20 files open and I am working on them and don't want to close any of the files because I need them all.

Is there any way to merge all the tabs on to one tab as a single drop-down list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there is any way to merge all the tabs as a single drop-down list?

Not explicitly.

Workaround:

- You can hide the tabs using:

  menu item "Settings" > "Preferences" > "General" > "Tab bar" > enable "Hide" > click "Close"

  [image]
- Access the first 10 open files from the menu item "Window"

  [image]
- Access other open files using:

  menu item "Window" > "Windows..." > select a window > click "Activate" > click "OK"

  [image]

That seems to be close to what you are asking for.

Comment: thanks @DavidPostill, yes this is a way which can work for me. :)